# how to set response value in springcloud gateway with GlobalFilter

Tags: spring-cloud, gateway

how to set response value in springcloud gateway with GlobalFilter?
I don't know use which method in ServerHttpResponse.

```
public class AuthGlobalFilterFilter1 implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    Object key =  exchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().get("key");
    if(key==null){
        ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse =  exchange.getResponse();
        serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        //in here,I want set the value of response body.such as json string "{"status":401}"
        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }
    return chain.filter(exchange);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I have solved it.

```
        ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse = exchange.getResponse();
    serverHttpResponse.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
    byte[] response =  "{\"status\":\"erroe\",\"message\":\"error happen\"}".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);;
    DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(response);
    return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));
```